# Sorting a list of objects by property in Matlab, and then deleting the smallest one

Tags: algorithm, matlab, oop, sorting

I'm trying to use Matlab to implement the MDO algorithm, which requires me to sort an array of objects of a custom-defined mdoVertex class by their degree, and then delete the one with the smallest degree value. My first attempt was this:

```
for i = 1:m
    if graph(i).degree < minDegree
        minDegree = graph(i).degree;
        elimObject = graph(i);
    end
end
```

Matlab is complaining that elimObject, or the object to be eliminated after the loop executes, is an undefined function or variable.  How, then, can I keep track of not only the current smallest degree the loop has encountered, but also which object it corresponded to? 'graph' is the name of the array holding all of my vertex objects.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're somehow trying to call `clear` on the object returned from your function.  Or is it just a few lines of code in a script?  I'm guessing here.  In any event, calling `clear` won't work.  As you've noticed, `clear` expects to be given a variable name.

But in this case, you're not trying to delete a variable, you're trying to remove an element from an array.  For that, you do `arrayname(indextodelete) = [];`

So I think that you want...

```
minDegree = inf; % See what I did there?  I defined the variable, and I did it in such a way that I KNOW that the first vertex will satisfy the condition.
for i = 1:length(graph) % Properly loop over the entire graph
    if graph(i).degree < minDegree % The first vertex will definitely satisfy this.  Maybe another one (or more) will later!
        minDegree = graph(i).degree;
        minDegreeIndex = i; % Don't record the value, just remember WHERE it is in the array.
    end
end
graph(minDegreeIndex) = []; % Now, remove the element that you identified from the array!
```

(By the way, you never showed us *how* you tried to eliminate `elimObject`.  I assume that you called `clear (the object that you identified)`? You shouldn't make us guess; show us.)

Comment: I didn't call clear anywhere actually.  The line of code that's throwing the error is the assignment statement.

Comment: Which line?  `elimObject = graph(i)`?  Again, perhaps you should edit the question to make it clear exactly what you're doing, and *where* the error happens.  For example, the code that you wrote can't *possibly* work as-is, because minDegree doesn't exist before you try to do a comparison.  Or, wait, is *that* the variable that MATLAB is complaining about because it's undefined???